# Downloading Pyclip python module on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I need to install the Pyclip module for python but I cant find directions on how to do this on Ubuntu. does anyone here know? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt get update
sudo apt-get install python-clips
```